# Is it unsafe to call a mysql stored procedure with emulate prepares set to true?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm calling a mysql stored procedure through PDO that returns multiple result sets.

```
$sql = 'CALL multiple_results()';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
do {
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
   if ($rows) {
       print_r($rows);
   }
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

I had the **Emulate Prepared Statements** set to *false*, but this does not work. I believe it's because this attribute makes it so that I only receive one result set back.

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
```

When I change the attribute to *true* it works perfectly and I can retrieve both datasets

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
```

If I'm just calling a stored procedure is it really unsafe to set Emulate Prepared Statements to true?

Comment: you aren't using any variables to bind to the query so you should be alright

Comment: what if I use variables but they don't come from the user (eg. textbox)

Comment: if you know where they come from and that they are safe, again, you should be fine. if it's user input though, ALWAYS bind the variable through a prepared statement.